# Could low pressure compressor blades be made of aluminum?

Tags: turboprop, aerospace-materials

With the compressor blades on a gas turbine, could the low pressure blades be made of aluminum, or would it be catastrophic?

Edit: 
Like the 6061 alloy.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: If your turbine operates on steam or compressed air then I think it's feasible. But if you mean hot combustion gas at 1000+K temperature, then it would be very very hard.

Comment: You should be more specific. Which gas turbine?

Comment: @ManuH any? It's kind of a generalized qeustion

Comment: @Lilrags16 You may precise it in the question, and there is a chance the question will be closed as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, and they have been, in the early days. The blade speed is lower than can be reached using titanium or steel, so more stages are required.